# look up values in same table and restrict results when value is equal

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of customers that I need to build a query for a homework question. The **referredby** column contains the customer# of the customer that referred them from the same table.

The two parts of the question I am having issues with are:

1)I need to display the customer number, customer last name, customer city, customer zip code and zip code of the customer that referred the customer which can be found in the same table.

2) I need to restrict results to customers that are referred by customers with the same last name

**Table Structure**

```
CUSTOMERS
(customer#, lastname, firstname, email, address, city, state, zip, referredby, region)
```

This is what I've got so far

```
SELECT customer#, lastname, city, zip "Customer ZIP", referred "Referrer ZIP"
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE referred IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: What columns do you have for the referrer? Is there a "referrer last name" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look on INNER JOINS here to understand more: https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/joins/oracle-inner-join.php

Try this:

```
SELECT a.customer#, a.lastname, a.city, a.zip "Customer ZIP", b.zip "Referrer ZIP"
FROM 
CUSTOMERS a
INNER JOIN
CUSTOMERS b
ON
a.customer# = b.referredby
AND
a.lastname = b.lastname;
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked and I will do some more reading up on joins.